# What data structure should I use for a simple synchronized LIFO?

Tags: java, data-structures

What data structure should I use for a simple synchronized LIFO? I'm using Android Java 1.6. The problem with Java collections is that there are millions of slightly different classes and interfaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about standard [Stack](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html)? It is synchronized.

**UPDATE**

According to javadoc, you should use implementation of `Deque` instead of `Stack`. E.g. [LinkedBlockingDeque](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingDeque.html)

Comment: Even the documentation you linked says not to use `Stack` anymore and provides an alternative.

Comment: @JeremyP yes, I didn't notice. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

> #### Queues
>
> The java.util.concurrent ConcurrentLinkedQueue class supplies an efficient scalable thread-safe non-blocking FIFO queue. Five implementations in java.util.concurrent support the extended BlockingQueue interface, that defines blocking versions of put and take: LinkedBlockingQueue, ArrayBlockingQueue, SynchronousQueue, PriorityBlockingQueue, and DelayQueue. The different classes cover the most common usage contexts for producer-consumer, messaging, parallel tasking, and related concurrent designs. The BlockingDeque interface extends BlockingQueue to support both FIFO and LIFO (stack-based) operations. Class LinkedBlockingDeque provides an implementation.

*Quoted from [API Docs for Package java.util.concurrent](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html).*